# php {$var} meaning

Tags: php, syntax

HEllo,

What is the meaning of `{$var}` in PHP?

Example:

```
$query = "UPDATE table SET field = '{$var}'";
```

Thx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`{$var}` "shields" the variable name from surrounding characters.  For example:

```
$root = "stick";
echo "{$root}y"; # Adjectify!
```

Will output "sticky", where:

```
$root = "stick";
echo "$rooty"; # Adjectify! No, just kidding.
```

Will output nothing at all, since the variable `$rooty` doesn't exist.

It also allows you to use expressions that are more than just variable names, like array indexing or property access.

Comment: That, and I don't think you can access arrays without them, like `"{$arr['key']}"` ... or at least not if you use quotes around the key IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

The general purpose i've found with using {$var} is that it tells PHP to explicitly reference what is inside as a variable. It's most used when doing something like

```
$qry = "UPDATE table SET field = '{$var['myvar']}'"; or
$qry = "UPDATE table SET field = '{$var->property}'";
```

Without the {} around my variable inside the string, it wouldn't know when the variable began and ended and usually causes PHP to throw an error.

Comment: It won't cause an error, it will just try to stringify `$var` and append `->property` etc., which is usually not what the developer wants.

Answer (score 1):

It also allows you to do variable variables

```
$var = "Sup";
$sup = "Hello!";

echo ${$var};    // outputs Hello!
```

Answer (score 0):

$var is a variable, a symbolic name associated with a value and whose associated value may be changed
the {} makes sure it gets handled as one in it's context
all 4 of these are valid and mean the same thing...

```
$query = "UPDATE table SET field = '{$var}'";
$query = "UPDATE table SET field = '$var'";
$query = "UPDATE table SET field = '".$var."'";
$query = 'UPDATE table SET field = \''.$var.'\'';
```